# Is it possible to make Adobe Reader to only negate a page?

Tags: pdf-reader

Evince has a feature that inverts the colors, look:

[image]

But Adobe Acrobat doesn't seem to do it right, look:

[image]

It seems Adobe's Reader doesn't simply invert the colors, is there a way to make it have the same behavior as Evince?

Also look at this example (Adobe):

[image]

And this one (Evince):

[image]

Evince simply negates the page color while Adobe selects some elements and change it's colors.

Comment: The colors seem pretty inverted to me... The antialising might be different, but all in all I'm not sure what's wrong. Or is it the color of the small square on the bottom right?

Comment: Nope. Did you notice the line almost disapeared? If you read it with less zoom, it's impossible to see the line.

Comment: It seems there's a separation on Adobe Reader: Things that are background and things that are text, strangely, that line is not considered as text. Also notice that there are a lot of similar errors in other parts of the book. There's also another case: When a PDF book is made of scanned images, the negation does not occur in these scanned images.

Comment: Maybe you should try `Right click` -> `Page Display Preferences`, and in the `Rendering` section, choose `None` for smooth text, and uncheck everything beginning by "smooth".

Comment: Look the examples I just posted now.